# UIImageJPGRepresentation and UIImagePNGRepresentation crash

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, nsdata, uiimagejpegrepresentation

I have a ImagePicker and selecting on the image I want to upload it. 
For that I need to `UIImage` to`NSData`.
I have used `UIImagePNGRepresentation` and `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`. But both of the cases the app crash. 
It works well for simulator but it crash in device in the second time.
First time it works perfect.

Comment: Can you provide any code?

Comment: What's in the crash log?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

First, Before using method debug the image view object and after check the length of NSData you get after the conversion.